# How to implement set of async task with some condition in series?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, q, async.js

I have to write the following code in nodejs:

```
val1 = async1()
if(val1 == 0){
 val1 = async2()
}
val2 = async3(val1)
```

In the above code, `val1` and `val2` are the values returned from asyncronous functions `async1()`, `async2()` and `async3()` How can I implement it?

Comment: Is `val1` a Promise? does `async1` take a callback? Show us actual code.

Comment: @naomik actually the above is a pseudo code. `val1` is some integer value and `async1` can be designed to take a callback.

Comment: If `async1`, `async2`, and `async3` are in your control, I would recommend you have them return Promises. Promises offer a much better flow control mechanism compared to callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async).

The above pseudo code can be implemented by [waterfall](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#waterfalltasks-callback) method.

Sample Implementation:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        callback(null, async1());
    },
    function(val1, callback){
        if(val1==0){
            callback(null, async2());
        } else {
            callback(null, val1);
        }
    }, function(val1, callback){
        callback(null, async3(val1));
    }
    ], function(error, val2){
            <you get val2 here>
});
```